# Different Model Classes for Actor

Tags: getstream-io

I'm trying to figure out how to utilize Stream for Activity tracking and feed generation within my app.  The activity will be a mix of user generated content and then AI generated content.  The 'AI' components will not have User accounts and there are two different model types.  I'm investigating stream-django and how to utilize this.  I currently have 3 different models that will generated activities.

```
User
Group
Place
```

I have a way for a user to follow another User, Group or Place but not sure how to translate this into leveraging Stream though.  Is there something like ContentTypes in Stream?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at enrichment [here](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-django#activity-enrichment).

By default it will try to 'enrich' the object and actor fields in an activity, substituting those for the model instances. So a user might follow groups, places and other users and all those activities will occur in the users' timeline, the enricher will fetch the database objects for all the 'content types'.